# Opposite Constellation of Sagittarius A*

Tags: milky-way, constellations

Suppose an alien race fired a laser beam from the centre of the Milky Way, it went through the Sun and then off further out of the galaxy.  What Constellation would the light beam head towards, closest star also if possible?  Am not interested about how much devastation the light beam may or may not cause, just the journey and destination.

Would that direction be the quickest/shortest way out of the galaxy if we had a spaceship that could travel that fast?

Comment: Opposite constellation is Gemini, so it would roughly move towards Castor/Pollux.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "out of the galaxy" the quickest way would just be to go "up" or "down" out of the plane of the galaxy rather than traveling the full length of the disk.

Comment: @zephyr Except that it has to start at the center of the galaxy AND go through the Sun, and two points determine a line.

Comment: @zephyr Ack, I thought I'd "deleted" that comment after realizing you were answering a different part of the question. Please ignore my comment: I never meant to actually post it.

Comment: When i originally asked the question, I thought both questions would be the same answer.  The second question didn't actually have to go through the Sun, just the quickest way out.  So straight up to Polaris it is then.

Comment: Not Polaris, @Misc! That's twice wrong: (i) the direction to Polaris is not perpendicular to the ecliptic (the plane of the Solar System); and (ii) the ecliptic is inclined at an angle of about 60° to the galactic plane. According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_plane), you want to head for Arcturus.

Comment: Actually, the "Galactic North Pole" is at about 12h 51m RA, 27deg 8min DEC. This between Beta and Gamma Comae Berenices at 13h 12m/ 27d 53m and 12h 27m/ 28d 16m respectively (epoch J2000.0). FYI Polaris is at 2h 32m RA/ 89d 16m DEC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Center, the galactic center 
is at RA 17h 45m 40.04s, Dec -29° 00' 28.1" in the J2000 epoch.

The point opposite this would be RA 5h 45m 40.04s, Dec +29° 00' 28.1" 
(J2000).

The nearest star I could find to this position is a relatively 
uninteresting 16th magnitude star:

[image]

The nearest "interesting" star is HIP 27088, which is an 8th magnitude 
double star:

[image]

My calculations show this point is in Auriga, not Gemini, albeit just barely:

[image]

A slightly more zoomed out view:

[image]

As @zephyr notes, the fastest way out of our galaxy would be "straight up" (perpendicular to the plane of the galaxy), not away from the center, since the Milky Way's "height" is much smaller than its length/width.

If someone wants to replicate what I did on Stellarium and use RA/DEC grids, be sure to set the date to 1999 Dec 31 at noon GMT: the grids Stellarium displays are based on the current date, not J2000.

NOTE: http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/nomad lists even more stars than Stellarium (Stellarium uses only part of this catalog), so you might be able to find an even closer star to this point, but I was too lazy to do so.

EDIT: Newer versions of Stellarium let you overlay galactic coordinates. I'm too lazy to do this myself, but if someone else wants to, it would be a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for spending the time and effort of all those maps, much appreciated.  As mentioned above, they were two questions which I assumed had the same answer.